# how to edit the XSl style sheets to make a heading link to a site

Tags: xslt

I have a CQWP that I am using to pull data from various sites and display the site title as a heading, and the documents underneath. The site title displays as a heading. Is there a way to make the heading a link to the site?

Comment: Have you tried using a CEWP and grabbing it JQuery? You could then do an onclick function to send it where you want.

Answer (score 0):

like this here in a CEWP:

```
$(‘input[title$="TitleofHeading"]‘).click(function() { window.location.href("www.yoursite.com") });
```